# How to add sum of column in third row

Tags: r

I want to add sum of `till_5` as `Grand total` in last with new row. I'm trying `colSums` but it shows error as mentioned.

```
df1=rbind(df1,c("Grand Total",colSums(df1[,3],na.rm = T)))
#Error in colSums(df1[, 3], na.rm = T) : 
#  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

data set (df1)

```
origin  destination_city2   till_5
A   Chennai 72
B   Coimbatore  4
C   Jaipur  1
D   Ajmer   3
E   Jaipur  4
F   Kishangarh  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `colSums` works on a `data.frame` or `matrix`.  When we subset the data into a `vector` (`df1[,3]`), it loses the dimensions.  In case, we need to do `colSums(df1[3])` or `colSums(df1[,3, drop = FALSE])`.  But, for a single column as a `vector`, `sum` is only needed

```
rbind(df1, list(origin = "GrandTotal", destination_city2 = "", 
                    till_5 = sum(df1$till_5)))
#       origin destination_city2 till_5
#1          A           Chennai     72
#2          B        Coimbatore      4
#3          C            Jaipur      1
#4          D             Ajmer      3
#5          E            Jaipur      4
#6          F        Kishangarh      1
#7 GrandTotal                       85
```

Also, in the OP's example, there seems to be 3 columns, so we need to `rbind` with the same number of elements

Comment: thanks akrun! can you please help me out if I have multiple columns in dataframe for sum? what needs to be done then. so these can be one column or more as per report timings, this solution will work if I knows to columns only. 
this shows error:
df1=rbind(df1, c("Grand_Total","", colSums(df1[,3:ncol(df1)],na.rm  = T)))
this works if these are multiple column but for 1 column it shows error:
#Error in colSums(df1[, 3], na.rm = T) : 
#  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Comment: @VishanRana  This is based on dropping the dimensions, you need to use `colSums(df1[,3:ncol(df1), drop = TRUE],na.rm = T)))` or remove the comma i.e. `colSums(df1[3:ncol(df1)],na.rm = T)))`

Answer (score 1):

You want `sum(df1$till_5)`. It's only one value, so you probably don't want to assign it to a whole new row in the data frame.